# React и Spring приложение, webpack

Tags: javascript, java, json, reactjs, spring

Не получается сделать приложение Spring + React по туториалу https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

происходит вот такая вот ошибка(https://ibb.co/jvPr38x)
в туториале не показывает какие команды прописывать для npm, webpack.
как я сделал: сгенерировал package.json(npm init), сгенерировал package-lock.json.
В index.html у меня src="built/bundle.js". 
потом сделал npm install. создал по гайду webpack.config.js (npm i webpack-cli @webpack-cli/init и npx webpack-cli init)

с путями "/src/main/js/app.js" в "/src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js"

И мне вместо создания built/bundle.js мне создает папку(!) bundle.js и в ней index.html и main.3a6c22dd17de3ff92ad1.js

при npm run start запускает localhost:8080, но в терминале ошибки(не знаю как правильно ошибки вставить, что читабельно было, их много)

package.json:
`json
    {
  "name": "spring-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My webpack project",
  "main": "./src/main/js/app.js",
  "keywords": [
    "spring",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Korzhov",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^0.2.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "rest": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  }
}`

Comment: А что в package.json?

Comment: добавил в тему.